# How to store date value in hive timestamp?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I am trying to store the date and timestamp values in timestamp column using hive. The source file contain the values of date or sometimes timestamps.

Is there a way to read both date and timestamp by using the timestamp data type in hive.

**Input:**

```
2015-01-01  
2015-10-10 12:00:00.232
2016-02-01
```

**Output which I am getting:**

```
  null
  2015-10-10 12:00:00.232
  null
```

Is it possible to read both values by using timestamp data type.

**DDL:**

```
create external table mytime(id string ,t timestamp) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://xxx/data/dev/ind/'
```

Comment: convert the date value 2015-01-01 to datetime like 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000

Comment: you mean in the input file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive is similar to any other database in terms of datatype mapping and hence requires a uniform values for a specific column to be stored under a conformed datatype. The data in your file for second column has non-uniform data i.e, some are in date format while others in timestamp format.
In order to not to lose the date, as suggested by @Kishore , make sure you have a uniform datatype in the file and get the file with timestamp values as `2016-01-01 00:00:000` where there are only dates.

Comment: Basically we are trying make hive tables compatible to impala by changing the date data type to timestamp, Above problem arise due to hive timestamp not supporting to read date values.  So final conclusion is to modify the files in HDFS to pad time values. Intensive work to fix history files but no other option to go.

Comment: added a response below if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I was able think of a workaround. tried this with a small set of data:

1. Load the data with inconsistent date data into a hive table say table1 by making the column as string datatype .
2. Now create another table table2 with the datatype as timestamp for the required column and load the data from table1 to table2 using the transformation `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2 select id,if(length(tsstr) > 10, tsstr, concat(tsstr,' 00:00:00')) from table1;`
   This should load the data in required format.

   Code as below:

`

```
create table table1
(
id int,
tsstr string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/hive/table1.tb';

Data:
1,2015-04-15 00:00:00
2,2015-04-16 00:00:00
3,2015-04-17

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/cloudera/data/tsstr' INTO TABLE table1;


create table table2
(
id int,
mytimestamp timestamp
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/hive/table2.tb';

INSERT INTO TABLE table2 select id,if(length(tsstr) > 10, tsstr, concat(tsstr,' 00:00:00')) from table1;
```

Result shows up as expected:
[image]

Comment: Thanks , This is the only approach but for this to work we need to fix the history data too , Volume of data is huge. To make it production we need to reload all data.

Comment: Yes . this needs a re-crunching of data and history correction